# When does $\sum_n \sum_i a_nb_i = \sum_i \sum_n a_nb_i$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

May be trivial.

I am just wondering when
$$\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}} \underset{i=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}} a_nb_i = \underset{i=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}} \underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}} a_nb_i$$
assuming $a_n,b_i \in \bar{\mathbb{R}}$. In particular, the problem I am working with has every $0 < a_i,b_n < \infty$. If I expand the series and "reorder" the terms I see equality seems to hold. I am a little unsure of working with series like this. I am thinking it would be best to work with the definition of a series as the limit of partial sums but I tried this and it seemed a little out there so I thought I would ask here.

What I mean by working with series like this is for example something like
$$\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}} \underset{i=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}} 2^{-n}i^2 = \underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}} ( 2^{-n}1^2+2^{-n}2^{2}+2^{-n}3^{2}+ \cdots )=( 2^{-1}1^2+2^{-1}2^{2}+2^{-1}3^{2}+ \cdots ) + ( 2^{-2}1^2+2^{-2}2^{2}+2^{-2}3^{2}+ \cdots ) + ( 2^{-3}1^2+2^{-3}2^{2}+2^{-3}3^{2}+ \cdots )+\cdots$$
then "reordering" the terms to get
$$\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}} \underset{i=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}} 2^{-n}i^2 = (2^{-1}1^2+2^{-2}1^2+2^{-3}1^{2}+\cdots)+(2^{-1}2^2+2^{-2}2^{2}+\cdots)+\cdots=\underset{i=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}} \left[ 2^{-1}i^2+2^{-2}i^2+\cdots \right]=\underset{i=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}} \underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}2^{-n}i^2.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sufficient condition is absolute convergence. You can get this out of Fubini's theorem, or just prove it directly (see e.g. page xiii of http://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/measure-book1.pdf)

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it.